# This might be tricky... "Expected an Assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit of a newby to javascript and can't seem to wrap my head around this error. I apologize in advance if I could have done a better job posing my question, but I am not 100% on the lingo and can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Essentially the issue is this.

I have height and width inputs. I wanted to multiply those fields by each other to give me a Sq. Foot "Rectangle" Total in another input, which I was able to accomplish with this code.

```
$('#height1, #width1').keyup(function(){
    var height1 = parseFloat($('#height1').val()) || 0;
    var width1 = parseFloat($('#width1').val()) || 0;

    $('#sqfoot1').val(height1 * width1);    
});
```

However, the problem is that I may also need to calculate for Sq. Foot "Arch" Total instead.

It is one or the other, each unit will either be an arch or rectangle.
So I figured I could solve this with a condition.

If a radio button (arch1) was checked then it would disable the sqfoot1 field and set it's value to '', and use some iteration of the above code to then have sqfootarch1 get it's value from height1 * width1.

If the opposite was true and it was not checked, it would do the reverse, disabling sqfootarch1 and setting it's value to '' while allowing sqfoot1 field to continue using the above code. This is what I have so far.

```
document.getElementById('arch1').onchange = function() {
    if( $('#arch1').is(':checked') ) {
        document.getElementById('sqfoot1').disabled .val '';
    var height1a = parseFloat($('#height1').val()) || 0;
    var width1a = parseFloat($('#width1').val()) || 0;

    $('#sqfootarch1').val(height1a * width1a);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('sqfootarch1').disabled .val '';
    var height1 = parseFloat($('#height1').val()) || 0;
    var width1 = parseFloat($('#width1').val()) || 0;

    $('#sqfoot1').val(height1 * width1); 
    }
});
```

Is this even possible? Am I trying to do too much?

Again, I apologize if this just seems like a mess, and I would be happy to give any clarification needed to the best of my ability.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Here are the effected HTML units.

```
<span style="margin-right:2px">Arch <br>
    <span style="margin-right:2px"><input type="radio" 
    name="arch1" id="arch1" class="checkable" /><br>
<label>Yes</label></span>
<span style="margin-right:2px"><input type="radio" 
    name="arch1" id="archno1" class="checkable" checked /><br>
<label>No</label></span></span>


<span style="margin-right:15px">Width: <br>
<input class="text" type="number" name="width1" 
id="width1" style="width:30px" title="Measurements in decimal point 
values."></span>


<span style="margin-right:15px">Height: <br>
<input class="text" type="number" name="height1" 
id="height1" style="width:30px" title="Measurements in decimal point 
values.">
</span>


<span style="margin-right:15px">Sq. Ft. Rect.: <br>
<input class="text" type="number" name="sqfoot1" 
id="sqfoot1" style="width:30px" readonly /></span>                                                                     


<span style="margin-right:15px">Sq. Ft. Arch: <br>
<input class="text" type="number" name="sqfootarch1" 
id="sqfootarch1" style="width:30px" readonly /></span>
```

This is the code from http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Send me spam: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam" /></p>
<div data-bind="visible: wantsSpam">
    Preferred flavor of spam:
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
        spamFlavor: ko.observable("almond") // Initially selects only the Almond radio button
    };
 
    // ... then later ...
    viewModel.spamFlavor("msg"); // Now only Monosodium Glutamate is checked
</script>
```

It doesn't appear to work on here either. It's just a check box with some radio buttons, nothing actually happens.

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML and CSS, right here in your question (as a code snippet) so we can replicate your issue, understand it better and give you a working answer.

Comment: This line is wrong `document.getElementById('sqfoot1').disabled .val '';` as `.disabled` is a boolean that does not have a property called `.val` and there is no `=` between `.val` an `''` anyway.

Comment: Why are you using different inputs for the same thing. Just reuse the same inputs for both `sqfoot` and `sqfootArch`.

Comment: I believe I have all the relevant HTML there for you now, Scott.

Comment: Ibrahim, I would honestly be happy to do utilize either solution. But I am not sure how to go about executing your suggestion. Would you be willing to give a working implementation of that method?

As I am fairly novice at this, I am sure most of my code is riddled with redundancies lol.

Comment: I might need to use separate inputs, though. Because although I don't have it written this way yet, there will likely be other variables I need to add to calculate the sqfootarch total. Just trying to get the actual code to run first.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the line that is failing is this one;

```
document.getElementById('sqfoot1').disabled .val '';
```

You are using jQuery in other parts of the code, so if you want to use chaining you could do this;

```
$("#sqfoot1").disable().val("");
```

If you prefer to use regular javascript for that part, you'll have to break it into two statements.

```
let element = document.getElementById('sqfoot1');
element.disabled = true;
element.value = "";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Shadow. But I seem to be going further down the rabbit hole. I have been trying for the last hour to apply your recommendation to no avail.

I need it to update the "sq foot total" obtained from the "height" and "width" fields to the appropriate field based on the radio button selected.

I also need it to be triggered by both the "keyup" function on the height and width or by changing the radio button selection.

It seems I can get one or the other working. But not both.

Any further info you could give me on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't use jQuery for what you're talking about... it seems like more a of a knockout.js job to me... Perhaps it would be worth you going through the start of their interactive tutorial.

Comment: I have it installed now, I will dig around on the website and see if I can find what I'm looking for in there. I'll update on here whether I found it or not, thank you.

Comment: Hello, I am still unable to get this to work even with knockout.js.

I am not sure if there is something wrong elsewhere in my site, but I have attempted every possible option I can see to "disable" or "hide" a field based on the condition of a radio button or check box, and no dice.

So I decided I would take an example right off their page and test that. Still didn't work. They have a check box that, when checked, should cause a few radio buttons to show up. On my site they are all visible the entire time. I have tried plugging it into multiple areas of my site, same result everywhere.

Comment: A quick update, I think I just had that light bulb moment. Through digging through the site some more, doing the tutorials, I now have their example working. I should be able to apply this to what I am needing. Again, I will update when I get home and can actually implement it to my own site.